# Get Processor Name in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, processor

I have a number of production servers that I'm attempting to audit. They are all on separate networks, all running PowerShell 2.0, and due to time constraints, I am unable to reboot the servers in order to upgrade PowerShell to a higher version.  Anyhow, I'm trying to return the name of the processor.  I can see it when I run:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_Processor
```

But when I run:

```
(Get-WMIObject win32_Processor).Name
```

It doesn't return any results.  This works in other versions of PowerShell, but I can't get it to work in 2.0.  Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: `$env:PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER` ?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go via pipe in powershell 2.0:

This should work in 2.0:

`Get-WMIObject win32_Processor | select name`